# Joint pmf of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The joint pmf of two discrete random variables I and J is

$$f(i, j) = b(|i|+|j|) \ for\   i = -1, 0, 1 \ and \ |i+j| \le 1 \ where \ i \ and \ j \ are \ both \ integers$$

I'm suppose to find constant b, and then find $$ P(I + J > 1) $$

I know x takes the values -1,0,1
so in order to stay within the bounds of the conditions, y can take the values
-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, right?

When I did it that way for my b, I found 1/14

But then for the next part, the only places where I + J are greater than 1 are
f(0,2), f(1,1), and f(1,2), all of which have 0 probability, according to the condition

$$ \ |i+j| \ge 1 $$

Which makes me think I'm doing something wrong

If anyone could put me on the right track, I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: $|i+j| \ge 1 $ ?? This condition is met for zillions of $j$'s. Are you sure that this is the condition?

Comment: They're both integers, sorry

Comment: Still: 1+100000 > or equals 1...

Comment: $$f(i, j) = b(|i|+|j|) \ for\   i = -1, 0, 1 \ and \ |i+j| \ge 1 \ where \ i \ and \ j \ are \ both \ integers$$
Please react. The condition above might be wrong. Think of $I=1$ and $J=10000$. The condition does not put any limit on $J$.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's less than or equal to...I knew that (it doesn't answer my question), but I wrote it wrong anyway. Didn't catch my mistake.

Comment: Huhh. I managed to save your life!

Comment: Is it not possible that the question is $$P(|I|+|J|>1)=??$$

Comment: Did you draw a picture of the setting?

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have corrected one error, it seems $b = 1/14$ is correct.

Because $|i + j| \le 1$ means $-1 \le i + j \le 1$, it is obvious that
$P(I + J > 1) = 0$.

A more interesting question might be to ask for $P(I + J < 1).$ I'm wondering
if that was the question intended. The event here excludes
points $(1, 0),$ $(0, 1),$ and $(-1, 2),$ and I'll let you figure the
probability of that.